# The getter 'placeName' was called on null

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

I created a class Address with the following strings

```
class Address{
  String placeName='';
  double latitude;
  double longitude;
  String placeId= '';
  String placeFormattedAddress= '';
  Address(
      {
        this.placeId,
        this.latitude,
        this.longitude,
        this.placeName,
        this.placeFormattedAddress,
      });

}
```

and I tried to get the address from google maps and then pass the value using Provider Package

```
class HelperMethods{
  static Future<String> findCordinateAddress(Position position, context) async {

    String placeAddress = '';

    var connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    if(connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.mobile && connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.wifi){
      return placeAddress;
    }

    String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${position.latitude},${position.longitude}&key=$mapKey';

    var response = await RequestHelper.getRequest(url);

    if(response != 'failed'){
      placeAddress = response['results'][0]['formatted_address'];

      Address pickupAddress = new Address();
      pickupAddress.longitude = position.longitude;
      pickupAddress.latitude = position.latitude;
      pickupAddress.placeName = placeAddress;

      Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).updatePickupAddress(pickupAddress);

    }

    return placeAddress;

  }

}
```

but the thing is that it takes some time
so, when I try to open the page where the address will be displayed it shows the error
and it disappeared after the address is ready, so is there anyway to prevent this from happening ?
pass a different value until the address is ready ???

The getter 'placeName' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: placeName

```
    String address = Provider.of<AppData>(context).pickupAddress.placeName ?? '';

and then I print or display the content of the address
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE :
it was so easy but I couldn't see it before
just add question mark (?) after .pickupaddress

```html
String address = Provider.of<AppData>(context).pickupAddress?.placeName ?? '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use conditions in your UI code. Something like :

```
if(placeName != null)
  Text(placeName)

// null-aware operator
Text(placeName ?? "name is null")

// ternary operator
placeName != null ? Text(placeName) : CircularProgressIndicator()
```